# Download custom font with ZPL

Tags: fonts, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to download custom font .TTF to the Zebra printer by using ZPL commands.
There is a ZPL command **~DY** which can download fonts to the printer. This command has the following parameters 
~DYd:f,b,x,t,w,data

- d- file location Accepted Values: R:, E:,B:,A:
- f - file name
- b - format downloaded Accepted Values:B (.TTF)
- x - extension of file Accepted Values:T (TTF)
- t - number of bytes in file Accepted Values:.TTF
- w - number of bytes per row Accepted Values:.TTF
- data - ASCII or ZB64 - Accepted Values:A,P or binary - Accepted Values:B,C

but I can't find any detailed information about file location parameter. What does this all parameters **R:,E:,B:,A:** mean? Could someone explain this zpl command and show some examplehow to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R E B A are the file locations just like C: D: are on a computer.  If im right E: is the Flash and R: is the DRAM.  Either one will put it in the right folder for you.  you can then just call the font from its location "E:Font"

Hope this helps

Comment: Please help, i have .TTF file , how i upload, i m using utility software but not sucess